# Is there a way to make CORS work for a single route in Gin Go

Tags: go, server, cors, api-design, go-gin

I am trying to make a single gin server endpoint be accessible by a certain origin. I have tried some packages such as https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors but from what I understand it sets CORS to your whole server.

For example I have multiple routes but I only want "/scrape" to be allowed to be accessed by "google.com"

- /data "all origins"
- /ping "all origins"
- /scrape "google.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. It(https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors) just a **middleware**.

```golang
package main

import (
  "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
  "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
  router := gin.Default()

  // CORS for example.com and example.net origins
  router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"example.com"},
    AllowOriginFunc: func(origin string) bool {
      return origin == "example.net"
    }})).GET("/scrape", func(c *gin.Context) {
     // serve something
  })

  allOrigins := router.Group("/")
  allOrigins.Use(cors.Default())
  allOrigins.GET("/data", func(c *gin.Context) {
     // serve something
  })
  allOrigins.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
     // serve something
  })

  router.Run()
}
```

See more middleware example: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#using-middleware

Comment: Will this work if I also have other routes as well

for example I have these routes but I only want "/scrape" to be allowed to be accessed by "google.com"

- /data "all origins"
- /ping "all origins"
- /scrape "google.com"

Comment: I made an edit to my initial question to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: @xilaluna Any question about the code?

Comment: I just implemented it, it works thx so much

Comment: No Fetch-compliant browser would send an `Origin` header with value `example.net`. Did you mean `https://example.net`? Same question about `example.com`.

Comment: @jub0bs Yes, stw didn't allow me to write the URL with `https` or `http` protocol in my code.

Comment: @spike014 What? Can you clarify your last comment?

Comment: @jub0bs Never mind, you can replace `example.com` to any URL you want.